# hibernate search not tokenizing document id

Tags: tokenize, hibernate-search

Does somebody know if there is a workaround for enabling hibernate-search to tokenize the @DocumentId of an entity?  According to the docs: *"By design, an id has to be stored and must not be tokenized. It is also always string encoded, even if the id is a number."*

Answer (score 1):

Just add an additional `@Field` annotation. Any field can be indexed multiple times, either by using `@Fields` or in the case of document id either by adding an additional `@Field` to the property annotated with `@DocumentId` resp `@Id`, for example:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Animal {
    @Id
    @Field(name="tokenized_id")
    private String id;

    // ...
}
```

no need for a transient field.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a transient field, and on getter method return your filed annotated with @Id or @DocumentId, then you can apply your tokenizers/filters on that transient field. After all are set, you can create your query and search on transient field rather than your entity primary key.